# Twilio Programable Voice TwilioVoice.connect() No response

Tags: android, react-native, twilio-programmable-voice

I am working on React Native app to make a call using Twilio programmable voice call I am able to integrate it for android but call function is not working

```
await TwilioVoice.initWithToken(token)
returns return "initialized:true"
But 
TwilioVoice.addEventListener('deviceReady', () => {
this.setState({ twilioInited: true });
});
is not working
to make a call even if I have manually set it to true but no response on 
makeCall button
shown in blow code 
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View,TouchableOpacity,             
PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';
import TwilioVoice from 'react-native-twilio-programmable-voice';
```

```js
await TwilioVoice.initWithToken(token)
returns return "initialized:true"
But 
TwilioVoice.addEventListener('deviceReady', () => {
this.setState({ twilioInited: true });
});
is not working
to make a call even if I have manually set it to true but no response on 
makeCall button
shown in blow code 
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View,TouchableOpacity,             
PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';
import TwilioVoice from 'react-native-twilio-programmable-voice';
const instructions = Platform.select({
ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
android:
'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});
type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component
<Props>
{
state = {
twilioInited: false
};
getAuthToken = () => {
return fetch('http.api.?pincode=Test&method=access_token&format=json', { //replace c2a19b17.ngrok.io with your link (from Step 1)
method: 'get',
})
.then(response => response.text())
.catch((error) => console.error(error));
}
getMicrophonePermission = () => {
const audioPermission = PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECORD_AUDIO;
return PermissionsAndroid.check(audioPermission).then(async result => {
if (!result) {
const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(audioPermission, {
title: 'Microphone Permission',
message: 'App needs access to you microphone ' + 'so you can talk with other users.',
});
}
});
}
/*async componentWillMount() {
const token = await this.getAuthToken();
alert(token);
// or 
TwilioVoice.initWithToken(token);
TwilioVoice.Device.connect({To: '+12054764217'});
TwilioVoice.addEventListener('deviceReady', () => {
this.setState({ twilioInited: true });
});
}*/
initTwilio = async () => {
const token = await this.getAuthToken();
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
await this.getMicrophonePermission();
}
const success = await TwilioVoice.initWithToken(token)
alert(JSON.stringify(success));// return "initialized:true"
TwilioVoice.addEventListener('deviceReady', () => {
this.setState({ twilioInited: true });
});
if (Platform.OS === 'ios') { //required for ios
TwilioVoice.configureCallKit({
appName: 'ReactNativeTwilioExampleApp',
});
}
};
makeCall = () => TwilioVoice.connect({'To': '+12054764217'})
render() {
return (
<View style={styles.container}>
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>
      this.initTwilio()}>
      <View>
         <Text>Init Twilio</Text>
      </View>
   </TouchableOpacity>
   <TouchableOpacity disabled={!this.state.twilioInited} onPress={() =>
      this.makeCall()}>
      <View>
         <Text>Make call ({this.state.twilioInited ? 'ready' : 'not ready'})</Text>
      </View>
   </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
);
}
}
```

[image: Application Screen]

Answer (score 1):

if you are using voice-quickstart-server-node from Twilio as your server, make sure to change request.body.to and request.query.to to request.body.To and request.query.To. the code is case sensitive and the change is required to make calls. for a working example of making a call with connect(), check out https://medium.com/@edzh1/create-a-twilio-voip-calls-in-a-react-native-app-35a729a9613d

Comment: I had changed my platform now I am working on android, thanks for reply

Comment: Hi Hassan Kalhoro were you able to resolve this issue? @simpleCoder I am trying to implement twilio audio calls using the same medium link mentioned in the comment above. I am getting err: "Registration failed" in deviceNotReady call back. TwilioVoice.initWithToken is giving me success. but i am getting registration failed error. what could be the error ?